# Domain Based C# Licensing

Tags: c#, .net, licensing, cryptography

I have build a control in c# that users can download and use in their websites. I will be charging for this control, and want the ability to create a license key that only works for specific domains (the domain the control is used on).

I've looked at Rhino Licensing by ayende - but it was lacking any information on how to include it into my own project.

I'm looking for one of the following - a detailed tutorial for handling domain based licensing in c# or suggestions on specific free solutions.

Comment: you can get a list of accepted domains and check if domain is accepted or not!

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more detailed.

Comment: Can you find out which domain the control is running on, or do you need that as part of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you can find out which domain the control is running for at the moment, then the way I would do this would be to use a license file that is cryptographically signed.

Basically, on your end, you:

1. Generate a license file, which contains the date the license was created, if necessary the date the license expires, and the domain(s) that the license is valid for
2. Encrypt, or at least sign, the file cryptographically, using a PKI system, like RSA (built into .NET)
3. Submit this encrypted/signed license file to the person(s) setting up their domain using your control

On their end, they would:

1. Drop the license file into an agreed upon location, for instance the App_Data or similar type of folder
2. If necessary, change the web.config file to point to this license file, if the location isn't worked out automatically

In the code, you would:

1. Bundle the public key that goes along with the private key you used to encrypt/sign the license file, as part of the control, or as a separate file alongside your control
2. Decrypt and verify the signature, this ensures that the license file is not tampered with, and that it comes directly from you
3. Verify that the domain the control is running under is listed in the license file
4. Take action if not

Comment: Lassee - This sounds great. I am very new to cryptography, private/public keys, and generating licenses. Do you know of any code tutorials for doing this? A code library maybe?

Comment: For "code library", everything is built into .NET. As for a tutorial, I don't know of any specific tutorials for this, but I can almost guarantee there are some, I just don't know about them.

Answer (score 0):

Your control should be able to access the `Request.Url` property to determine the domain that the current request is being executed for, specifically the `Request.Url.Host` property. Once you've got that it's up to you how you determine if the current domain name is "licensed" or not.

You've a couple of options:

- Some form of license key that you generate, possibly a hash that matches the hash of the domain name.
- Calling a web service (that you host) to determine if the domain is licensed for your control (far from ideal as this could be, reasonably, blocked by your customers web server)
- Providing a bespoke assembly to each customer that has the permitted domain hard-coded inside it.

One thing worth mentioning is, consider disabling any licensing checks that you make when the `Request.IsLocal` property is `true` so that local testing doesn't cause licensing checks. You could also consider adding specific exclusions for private IP ranges (e.g. 10.x.x.x) so that build servers, test servers, etc,.. don't require licensing (unless your control is likely to be used on intranets, etc,..).